# HP Proliant ML150 G3 physical drive size limit

Tags: storage, hp, hp-proliant

Apologies if this is a rather silly question, but I'm not very savvy when it comes to interpreting server documentation. The documentation (http://h18004.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/12527_na/12527_na.HTML) specifies that the maximum storage possible for this server is 4.5TB resulting from 6x750GB drives. It also mentions support for smaller drives (500GB, 250, etc.) but not larger ones. Since the total it can handle is 4.5TB, does this mean that it could support 4x1TB drives? My concern is that the hardware wouldn't be able to read the drives properly since 1TB is greater than the maximally "supported" capacity of 750GB drives. Is this concern unfounded or would the server not be able to use 1TB drives? I have searched around for an answer but have not been able to find one.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is at the side of the RAID controller. The RAID controller may or may not support larger drives.

If the server you have got has a E200 RAID controller, you have a good chance to succeed. From the [specifications](http://h18000.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/12460_na/12460_na.html) of the RAID controller in question HP E200/128 BBWC it supports SATA disks up to 3TB. So it is likely, that your system will work with large disks.

The reason this is not shown in the spec is that HP stops updating the specifications when it stops selling the product. ML150 G3 as the spec says was retired in 2008.

Your best bet is to get hold of a terabyte drive,  install it into the system and see if it is recognized and its full capacity is being used.

Also make sure that you have the latest firmware for the RAID controller.

Certainly HP would not support this configuration if it does not work.

Comment: Thanks, the only problem is that I have the drives, but was thinking of buying the server second-hand as a place to house them. I just wanted to be sure I didn't buy something that couldn't support the drives.

Comment: Sorry, of G3 servers I only have access to a DL 140 G3, but cannot use it for testing.

Answer (score 0):

The drive listing on the document is out of date. The ML 350 g3 was retired June 2008. I would suggest you look and see what type of drives you currently have and stick with those. The chassis comes in a hot plug and non-hot pluggable setup. If you have access to larger SATA/SAS drives then the ones listed you might try one. The documentation does not advance much after a chassis is retired.

The HP documents I have looked at say you can mix and match the SAS/SATA drives as needed. Most folks use the same disk type in order to make RAID optimized. Seems basic info but some people do not know so try and make all your drives of the same type and capacity.

Also the Check the firmware (amazing how many people do not do this) HP excerpt: In BIOS revisions prior to 11/03/2006, the default configuration for SATA models will not recognize when more than four drives are installed while running Microsoft Windows operating system. To recognize all six drives, AHCI mode has to be enabled and SATA AHCI driver installed. For further information on how to enable AHCI mode, please refer to the RTF card that is shipped with the server.